# How fully connected layer after global average pooling works in Resnet50?

Tags: deep-learning, resnet

I have resnet50 network with the top layers that include global average pooling with shape (1, 2048) and dense layer using softmax with shape (1, 3). How output shape of (1,2048) in global average pooling layer becomes (1, 3) for the output of dense layer? How does it work? I can't find a reliable source for explain this

Comment: Are you doing classification over 3 classes?

Comment: No, my model only have 3 classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dense or Fully connected layers are just matrix multiplication (with bias). So what you do is multiply a matrix with shape `1x2048` with another matrix of shape `2048x3` to get a output matrix of shape `1x3` which gives you scores for your 3 classes. Softmax converts these scores to probability. Of course your network learns the weights of these matrices using back-propagation.

Comment: Are the scores for the 3 classes are sorted by class indices?

Comment: no they should not be unless you explicitly sort them. They are given in the order as your training  dataset i.e., class label.

Comment: I trained my model using Keras and I think Keras automatically give particular image a class that taken from folder name where the image is located using ImageDataGenerator. But maybe I'm wrong. But if that's true, would that makes it explicitly sorted?

Comment: In that case you just need to know which image are assigned to which class. Use `print(validation_generator.class_indices)` to see the mapping.

Comment: Okay I'll check it. And what do you mean about another matrix of shape 2048x3? Where can I get that 2048x3 matrix?

Comment: You have to somehow transform a matrix of shape `1x2048` to matrix of shape `1x3`. To do so you need to multiply the first matrix with a matrix that have shape `2048x3`

Comment: I now understand how to get matrix of shape `1x3` . But I still don't understand how to get value of matrix that have shape of `2048x3` that will be use to multiply with the matrix shape of `1x2048`?

Comment: That is the part where 'learning' happens. Your neural network will find the values of that matrix (using back-propagation, iteratively) so that it's prediction is close to the actual ground truth values.

Comment: Are the process of finding the values of that matrix using back-propagation iteratively is also used when I test a new image after done training?

Comment: I think I understand it now. Thanks for your detail explanations