# Global pooling layer before or after Dense Layer

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create a new CNN model.
First I pass the rgb images(size 224x224) through a ResNet50 network. The output of the ResNet50 is (None,7, 7, 2048). I now have 2 different ways to proceed to reduce to a (None,512) vector.

Way 1: Insert a FCL(Dense layer) with 512 neurons followed by a global average pooling layer.

Way 2: Do a global average pooling layer first, and only after do the FCL with 512.

Are way 1 and 2 the same? If not, what is the difference?

I found a similar question, [How fully connected layer after global average pooling works in Resnet50?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490035/how-fully-connected-layer-after-global-average-pooling-works-in-resnet50) , but it doesn't explain the difference between doing first the global pooling.

Answer (score 0):

I believe placing global average pooling after FCL doesnt make sense.
The purpuse of global average pooling is to (partly) replace the FCL for the task of dimensionality reduction after the CNN layers while using less parameters (thus making the overfitting less probable). Some people still place a small FCL after the global average pooling.

A nice explanation can be found here: https://www.quora.com/Why-was-global-average-pooling-used-instead-of-a-fully-connected-layer-in-GoogLeNet-and-how-was-it-different